# Reroute URLs like Facebook and WordPress

Tags: php, .htaccess, parsing

I am building an application using PHP and was wondering how I would goo about turning a URL like "http://localhost/app/index.php?function=viewAssignments&id=14 into something like http://localhost/app/assignments/14 without having to create a folder called assignments and a page for every assignment.  (That's obviously unrealistic).

I already learned how to change the htaccess to make individual PHP files be accessible without actually typing .php at the end, but is there some way to make clean URLs like how I mentioned?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your server supports mod_rewrite, then you can accomplish this simply by creating a file in your directory called `.htaccess` and copy this code into the file,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /app/index.php?function=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Which will take something like this,

> http://localhost/app/index.php?function=viewAssignments&id=14

to look like this,

> http://localhost/app/viewAssignments/14

Comment: Excellent, this is just what I was looking for!  Thank you very much :)